# Is there a difference between 'over two days' and 'over a period of two days'?

Tags: sentence-construction

Person A wants person B to drink the juice they made **over two days**, i.e. they don't want them to drink it all on the first day, and so they tell person B, "Drink this **over two days**". Can they also say, "Drink this **over a period of two days**"? Are both correct? Is there any other way to say this?

Comment: You can say "Don't drink this *all at once*, but finish it *a little at a time* over two days."  The phrase "a period of"  is redundant and doesn't make the instruction any clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, over/during (a period of) two days:

One of the meaning and usage of ***[over](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/over)*** refers to:

> - ***during something, or while doing something***:
>
>   - *I was in Seattle over the summer.
>       Shall we discuss it over lunch/over a drink?
>       They took/spent an hour over lunch (= their meal lasted an hour).
>       It's fascinating to watch how a baby changes and develops over time (= as time passes).*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Although in your example the phrase "over two days" is clearly used to mean over a period of two days, the phrase is frequently used to mean "more than" two days.

For example: It took over two days to finish the work.